# How to store a html element and present it in another view?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a collection of buttons that add a list item to an existing list when clicked. In theory the list is a client's order and its created by clicking on the buttons. To start a new order I created a button called print that empty's the list.

this is the html:

```
 <ol class="order"></ol>
        <pre class="totalLine">Total:                 0.00</pre>
```

When one of the buttons is clicked:

```
 function AddItem(Name, Price, ID) {
                sum += parseInt(Price);
                ID = "Dish" + ID;
                   $(".order").append(
                        $('<li/>').addClass( ID).addClass("list-group-item").text(Name).append(
                            $('<span/>').addClass("badge").text(Price)
                        ));
                  
                $(".totalLine").text("Total:" + "                " + sum.toFixed(2));
            }
```

Print function:

function print() {

```
        $(".order").empty();
        sum = 0;
        document.getElementsByClassName("totalLine")[0].innerHTML = "Total:" + "                " + sum.toFixed(2);
    }
```

I would like to create another view called "AllOrders" for example in which the client will be able to examine all the orders (or in other words lists) that have been created. I'm not sure what the best way to go about this is or even how to start. I assuming I need to send a list of all the orders to the AllOrderscontroller but I'm not sure how to do that.

Someone told me I should use Ajax but I'm not sure how to apply that here.

I couldn't find something similar but any advice on where I can or what i should read up on would be highly appreciated.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's going to be hard to provide a complete answer in one post as there are many pieces, but namely:

- The server knows nothing about these orders since the list is building up on the client-side so if you want to be able to redirect to a new view through a redirect, the controller won't know what was added on the client.
- You need to ship it back to the back-end somehow and store it.  Preferrably that is where a database comes in.
- You can:

  1. When Adding an order, you could send an AJAX request to the server, and then store the order in the DB at that point.  You could send all the relevant info so that you can save the order.
  2. OR, you can create HTML input elements (hiddens, textboxes, etc.) that once the page is saved, all of that data gets posted to the server.  I did something with Kendo in this way (not that Kendo is required to do that though: https://onallthingsweb.wordpress.com/2016/06/27/asp-net-mvc-and-client-side-lists-with-kendo/)
- There are multiple ways to achieve this, but it can be a bit complicated and require a good understanding of either approach/technology you use.

Hope that helps with a starting reference.

Comment: Thanx Brian. I'm just wondering how the database will work. each order has multiple items of type dish (a model i created with name and price attributes). would it be a one to many relationship? and if so would it be possible to have the same dish in one order?

Comment: dishes 1---* selectedDishes *---1 customer